# While deploying war file in weblogic 10.3.6 im getting below error

Tags: java, weblogic, weblogic-10.x

Hi while deploying war file in weblogic server 10.3.6 im getting the below error

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.MutablePropertyValues.add(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/springframework/beans/MutablePropertyValues;

Do u know how this error is related???
im using 4.3.4.RELEASE

```
    <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>

 <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-data-oracle</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
```

is it related to web-servlet.xml??
here is my web-servelt.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.5.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd ">
```

Comment: `java.land.noSuchMethodError` ??? Really? Please do not type messages here, but copy-paste them!

Comment: your error message is both incomplete and incorrect. it's java.lang, not java.land. Are there any other typo's in there? Also, can you post the entire error message?

Comment: sorry guys.Please help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2563754/seelenvirtuose hi please help